# Is there a HTML helper that generates something like a label but with an ID attribute in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I need to generate some html, that I can access later from Jquery to inject a value later on.  On initial rendering, it should not show anything.  I am using MVC4.

Maybe something like

Is there a HTML helper? or do I need to create my own? if so, how do I go about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pass HtmlAttributes as parameters for the out-of-the-box MVC4 Helpers.

```
@Html.Label("", new { id = "yourID"})
```

But, maybe you just need a `<span id="yourID"></span>`

And you only need a helper for this, if you pretend to use it several times.

If you want to create an helper extension:

```
public static MvcHtmlString CustomLabel(this HtmlHelper helper, string labelId, string content = "")
{
    var span= new TagBuilder("span");
        span.Attributes.Add("id", labelId);
        span.SetInnerText(content)

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(span.ToString());
}
```

You could add another parameters to set CSS class or something like that.

Then, in your view you use it like this:

```
@Html.CustomLabel("yourID", "Initial Text")
```

**EDIT: For strongly typed Html Helpers see this:**

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/389747/Custom-Strongly-typed-HtmlHelpers-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Any way, in your case, would just create one this way: `@Html.CustomLabel(m=>m.YourID, "Initial Value")`  so that if you have the Initial Value in the model, you can do `Model.InitValue` instead of harcoding it like I did previously.

Comment: Thanks for that, but what do I have to change in the customLabel function to be able to do this?  @Html.CustomLabel(m=>m.YourID, m.InitialText)

Comment: There I added some more info... sample code is found in the link provided. Hope it helps!